# How to execute certain code when returning to a view swift

Tags: ios, swift, viewdidload

When reversing the segue of a view, I would like to have certain code performed. This is unlike viewdidload, or viewdidappear, because I don't want it to run when the app first launches, as it is my initial view controller, but only when returning from another view.

How do I go about achieving this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a delegate for this sort of thing, here is the first [tutorial i saw on google about it](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/swift-from-scratch-delegation-and-properties--cms-23445) but can google for some different ones. delegation is a key coding pattern that all iOS devs should know about and when to use.

So in your case, your first view controller will be a delegate of the second one, which will allow the second vc to execute methods on the first vc when it sees fit, and for this case i would assume before the second vc goes back to the first

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way is to keep some boolean propery (e.g. `Bool firstAppear`) then initialize it with true in viewDidLoad method, and then in viewDidAppear:

```
if firstAppear {
  firstAppear = false
  return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear methods. They called not just one time, but every time, your view controller appearing.
viewDidLoad called just one time after view controller loading

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider two viewcontrollers VC1 and VC2. You are now in VC2 and trying to navigate back. in ViewWillDisappear of VC2 try this code.

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "mykey")
```

And now you are navigating back to VC1. In VC1 ViewWillAppear use this code

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let mykey = defaults.boolForKey("mykey")
    if mykey {
        defaults.setBool(false, forKey: "mykey")
        //execute your code here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can set this for example in your **AppDelegate**:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
...
   let alreadyLaunched = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("alreadyLaunched")
   if alreadyLaunched  {
      print("This is not the first app launch.")
   }
   else {
       print("First app launch, setting NSUserDefault.")
       NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "alreadyLaunched")
   }
}
```

Then check wherever you want:

```
let alreadyLaunched = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("alreadyLaunched")
if alreadyLaunched  {
   print("This is not the first app launch.")
}
```